# Did an answer just get deleted on this question?

Tags: support, specific-question

[Specify --no-highlight-code in Babel Require Hook options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30938871/specify-no-highlight-code-in-babel-require-hook-options)

I *think* there was an answer posted on this question and it's gone now. Could someone with enough privileges to see the deleted answer please confirm whether there actually was an answer posted and just got deleted, or am I mistaken?

Comment: I'm Surprised you didn't get the tumbleweed badge for that actually. As it had no answers, no comments, and only 15 views after a month when you posted this.

Comment: I deserve a mirage badge

Comment: You'd have a notification in your In-box, right? Even if the answer gets deleted in the mean time. I have seen this happen with comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no deleted answers on that question.